# IOS Simulator problem "Failed to launch iOS Simulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds"

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, ios-simulator

So, I have a problem with the iOS simulator. Every time I try to launch my Flutter project on the iOS simulator, I get this error in VS Code: 'Failed to launch iOS Simulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds.'

I have tried different methods from various forums and YouTube guides, but none of them worked for me :( I also attempted to reinstall my IDE (VS Code), clean the cache, and delete Xcode. I even reinstalled the Flutter SDK, but I still couldn't find a solution to this problem. The iOS simulator shows as 'Offline' in the IDE, even though it's already running.

[Available devices in IDE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6AkW.png)

[Flutter doctor result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT3ks.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This answer helped me to solve the issue:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429697/cant-create-new-ios-simulator-on-xcode#:~:text=2023%20Solution%3A%20Download%20More%20Simulator%20Runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429697/cant-create-new-ios-simulator-on-xcode#:%7E:text=2023%20Solution%3A%20Download%20More%20Simulator%20Runtimes)

In short terms:

1. Open xcode
2. Open Devices and Simulators and go to the Simulators section, which is next to Devices.
3. Press "+" button down-left corner
4. Click OS Version and select "Download more simulators runtime".
5. Delete iOS 17.0
6. Press "+" button down-left corner
7. Select iOS
8. Select "iOS 16.4 Simulator" and wait till the installation finishes.
9. You will see many simulators in the "Devices and Simulators" section till the iPhone 14, but not 15.
10. Open a simulator now with cmd + space -> Simulator.app

To run the iPhone 15, you need to update the iOS to 17.0, but I fall into the same problem, and I need to repeat the process again. So, I will keep working with the iPhone 14 till some additional updates come and fix this problem.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1 - Open Xcode and go to preferences - > locations - > Command Line Tools and select Xcode 10 or above

2 - Close the VScode and open it. You might see IOS Simulator option there.

But previously you must close simulator also (Right click on Simulator in the Dock -> "Quit")

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error after I reinstalled xcode.
I solved it in the following way.

1. GET iOS Simulator on [XCode > Settings > Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQmA3.png)
2. Relaunch iOS Simulator

I think it was necessary to reinstall the ios simulator.